# Question about subgroup of $Z_p^{\times}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let g, h be elements of $Z_p^{\times}$, and $h\notin\langle g\rangle$, and $\langle g\rangle \neq Z_p^{\times}$, where p is a odd prime. let m be the order of $\langle g\rangle$, n be the order of $\langle h\rangle$, without use the knowledge that $Z_p^{\times}$ is cyclic, can we prove that for any such, m, n, gcd(m, n) is never equal n.

If we use $Z_p^{\times}$ is cyclic this is easy to show, I don't know how to prove it without using cyclic.

Comment: Unless $g=1$ and $m=1$?

Comment: @aschepler yes unless that.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much not true. As a comment mentions, the identity element is a counterexample, that is, take $g = e$ and any $h \neq e$. You can do better, though. Take any prime $p$, say $p = 5$. We know that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times}$ is the cyclic group of order $4$, which has an element of order $1$, an element of order $2$ (square any generator), and two elements of order $4$. Since $2 | 4$, you have an issue, again by taking $h$ to be the thing of larger order.

In fact, for any prime $p > 3$, we know that $p - 1$  will be a composite even number. Then, taking any generator $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times}$, we know that $\alpha$ has order $p - 1$ and $\alpha^2$ has order $\frac{p - 1}{2}$. Since $\frac{p - 1}{2} | p - 1$, your theorem doesn't hold for any $p > 3$, even if you exclude the identity element.

Edit: If you want a symmetric assumption that $g$ and $h$ generate trivially intersecting subgroups, this is very easily equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ being cyclic. Given $g, h$ with $\operatorname{ord}g | \operatorname{ord} h$ and $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = \{e\}$, the subgroup generated by $g$ and $h$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$, so $G$ is not cyclic. Conversely, if our group is not cyclic, there are trivially intersecting subgroups of order $q$ for prime $q$; taking the generators of those subgroups gives the desired $g, h$ in your statement. This means that any proof of this fact is essentially a proof that $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is cyclic.

Is there a reason you don't want to use/prove the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times}$ is cyclic?

Comment: I think as $h\notin\langle g\rangle$, $\langle h\rangle$  can not be subgroup of $\langle g\rangle$ and $\langle g\rangle$ can not be subgroup of $\langle h\rangle$

Comment: I wrote the response before you added that hypothesis. I'll try the updated version and edit if I figure anything out.

Comment: oh, I forgot the assumption $\langle g\rangle \neq Z_p^{\times}$

Comment: The assumption $h \notin \langle g \rangle$ doesn't mean that $\langle g \rangle$ can't be a subgroup of $h$. A counterexample takes $h$ to be any non-identity element of the group, and $g = e$. I'm assuming that you mean $h \notin \langle g \rangle$ and $g \notin langle h \rangle$.

Comment: yes you are right, the question should be gcd(m, n) is never equal n

Comment: Thanks! I think I mean g and h generate trivially intersecting subgroups, the reason is that I want to use this fact to prove $Z_p^*$ is cyclic...........